# Find the email address associated with a recaptcha account

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha

I have a wordpress website that uses recaptcha v2. The wordpress admin GUI obfuscates part of my private recaptcha key.
As I need access to this key, I want to find out which e-mail address is associated with my captcha account, in order to access the google recaptcha console.
Does anyone know how to find out which e-mail address is associated with a recaptcha account?

Answer (score 0):

if you go to [www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/) this will allow you to see your websites listed and you will be able to see what recaptcha keys are linked to where.

But from a security point i dont think there is a way to know what account set up the keys so you must login with the emails you suspect and see if they are listed